# failed to filter hook `get_terms_defaults`

Tags: filters, meta-query

I've failed to filter hook `get_terms_defaults`, I got this notices and it won't to load any term

> Notice: Undefined index: number in
>   /var/www/html/wp-merwaa/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1123
>
> Notice: Undefined index: offset in
>   /var/www/html/wp-merwaa/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1124
>
> Notice: Undefined index: parent in
>   /var/www/html/wp-merwaa/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1140
>
> Notice: Undefined index: get in
>   /var/www/html/wp-merwaa/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1144
>
> Notice: Undefined index: child_of in
>   /var/www/html/wp-merwaa/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1163
>
> Notice: Undefined index: parent in
>   /var/www/html/wp-merwaa/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1164
>
> Notice: Undefined index: orderby in
>   /var/www/html/wp-merwaa/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1189
>
> Notice: Undefined index: order in
>   /var/www/html/wp-merwaa/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1222
>
> Notice: Undefined index: exclude in
>   /var/www/html/wp-merwaa/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1235
>
> Notice: Undefined index: exclude_tree in
>   /var/www/html/wp-merwaa/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1236
>
> Notice: Undefined index: include in
>   /var/www/html/wp-merwaa/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1237
>
> Notice: Undefined index: childless in
>   /var/www/html/wp-merwaa/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1269

My code

```
public function exclude_not_allowed_terms() {
  if(!current_user_can('edit_others_posts')) {
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
      'key'       => 'owner',
      'value'     => get_current_user_id()
  );
}
add_filter('get_terms_defaults','exclude_not_allowed_terms');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters are for modifying data that's passed through them. You need to take the input, modify it, then `return` it.

```
function exclude_not_allowed_terms( $args, $taxonomies ) {
    if(!current_user_can('edit_others_posts')
      && in_array( 'my-taxonomy', $taxonomies ) ) {
        $args['meta_query'] = array(
            array(
                'key'    => 'owner',
                'value'  => get_current_user_id()
            )
        );
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'get_terms_defaults','exclude_not_allowed_terms', 20, 2 );
```

Comment: Now there's no notices, but the function doesn't work, terms isn't filtered by the meta

Comment: I've two meta(s) in the DB

`term_id           meta_key           meta_value
  24                     owner                      2
  23                     owner                      1`

Comment: meta query should be an array of arrays, edited above.

Comment: How can I specific this filter for special taxonomy?

Comment: I edited it to check taxonomy, not sure it's right. `$taxonomies` is the second argument passed to the filter, it's an array of taxonomies that were passed to `get_terms`. you also have to adjust `add_filter` to pass 2 arguments.